# Flexbox layout, push content when opening sidebar?

Tags: flexbox

So here is a picture reference for this question:

[image]

What I would like to do is, using flexbox layout 3 columns (left side bar, center content, *optional  right side bar). Basically, you have the 3 columns but only show the left side bar and content columns normally. Then, when the user clicks the menu button, have the right side bar content come into view (as shown by the red part in the drawing).

I figured the parent container to start would look something like:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

What else would be needed (especially for the right side push in sidebar) to get this working with flexbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close.

In order to make the content column grow when the right sidebar is hidden, you need a positive `flex-grow` on it.

And in order to make the `body` cover all the screen, remove its `margin` and use `height: 100%` on both `html` and `body`.

Here is a working example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('right').classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  background: #777;
}
#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #000;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="left" class="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <button type="button">Toggle sidebar</button>
</div>
<div id="right" class="sidebar hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually got something working by toggling a negative margin, but your solution seems to work in a fiddle as well. btw that code was just Stylus

Comment: Update: Tried you solution in my project, is there a way to use a transition with display none? With a negative margin, im able to have a nice easing transition and have the bar slide in. Toggling display abrubtly makes the sidebar appear/disappear which of course isnt wanted. Any ideas?

Comment: @Orbit `display` is not animatable. If you want a transition, try `width`, `flex-basis`, `margin`, ... [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltrm0vf2/)